# trying to group by generic_m_ai

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Our current application allows to filter data by NLSSORT=generic_m_ai, I'd like to be able to group by it as well.
Currently testing it with a small table, but keeping the 'case' statement similar to real query

This is how my table is created:

```
create table alex_collate_test
(aaa varchar(30),
bbb varchar(30), primary key(aaa, bbb))
insert into alex_collate_test values ('hi', 'bye')
insert into alex_collate_test values ('HI', 'bye')
insert into alex_collate_test values ('hi', 'BYE')
insert into alex_collate_test values ('HI', 'BYE')
insert into alex_collate_test values ('next', 'howdy')
```

Here's the regular group by:

```
select case when aaa is null or length(aaa) = 0 then '(blank) - '|| case when bbb is null then '' else bbb end  else aaa||' - '|| case when bbb is null then '' else bbb end  end mycolumn
from alex_collate_test
group by case when aaa is null or length(aaa) = 0 then '(blank) - '|| case when bbb is null then '' else bbb end  else aaa||' - '|| case when bbb is null then '' else bbb end  end
```

and get:

```
hi - BYE                                                        
HI - BYE                                                        
hi - bye                                                        
next - howdy                                                    
HI - bye
```

I'm following MSSQL's 'Collate' code, and wrapping the columns in 'NLSSORT':

```
select NLSSORT(case when aaa is null or length(aaa) = 0 then '(blank) - '|| case when bbb is null then '' else bbb end  else aaa||' - '|| case when bbb is null then '' else bbb end  end, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai') mycolumn
from alex_collate_test
group by NLSSORT(case when aaa is null or length(aaa) = 0 then '(blank) - '|| case when bbb is null then '' else bbb end  else aaa||' - '|| case when bbb is null then '' else bbb end  end , 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai')
```

And get this output:

```
0213021B01EF026701FE
023201FE0266025502130238026401F70267
```

At first it looks like hex, that I just have to convert to varchar, but if you look closer, it's not hex.  It has '02' - which isn't any normal character like 'hi' or 'bye'.

My expected output, or rather what I want to get is this:

```
HI - BYE
next - howdy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using MIN() can solve this problem

```
with qry as (
  select 
    case when aaa is null or length(aaa) = 0 then '(blank) - '|| 
    case when bbb is null then '' else bbb end  else aaa||' - '|| 
    case when bbb is null then '' else bbb end  
    end mycolumn 
  from alex_collate_test
)
select min( mycolumn ) mycolumn
from qry
group by NLSSORT( mycolumn, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai')
```

Here is a link to sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6934c/2

Answer (score 1):

[`NLSSORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions113.htm) gives you the bytes used to perform the sort using that value, and is a `RAW` value. So it's not directly useful.

But you can use that indirectly to achieve this. There may well be simpler methods, but using an analytic function that gives you a pseudo-column based on the sort order seems to work:

```
select mygroupcolumn
from (
  select mycolumn, first_value(mycolumn)
    over (partition by NLSSORT(mycolumn, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai')
      order by NLSSORT(mycolumn, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai')) as mygroupcolumn
  from (
    select case when aaa is null or length(aaa) = 0 then '(blank)' else aaa end
      || ' - ' || case when bbb is not null then bbb end as mycolumn
    from alex_collate_test
  )
)
group by mygroupcolumn
order by mygroupcolumn;

MYGROUPCOLUMN                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------
HI - BYE                                                        
next - howdy
```

I've also simplified (IMO) the `case` structure, but maybe that isn't so straightforward with your real one.

Adding a number column to check the result further, on the assumption you're grouping for a reason, your query gets:

```
MYCOLUMN                                                          SUM(CCC)
--------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
HI - BYE                                                                 8 
HI - bye                                                                 2 
hi - BYE                                                                 4 
hi - bye                                                                 1 
next - howdy                                                            16
```

And mine, with a tweak to get that `ccc` value out from the inner queries:

```
select mygroupcolumn, sum(ccc)
from (
  select mycolumn, ccc, first_value(mycolumn)
    over (partition by NLSSORT(mycolumn, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai')
      order by NLSSORT(mycolumn, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai')) as mygroupcolumn
  from (
    select case when aaa is null or length(aaa) = 0 then '(blank)' else aaa end
      || ' - ' || case when bbb is not null then bbb end as mycolumn, ccc
    from alex_collate_test
  )
)
group by mygroupcolumn
order by mygroupcolumn;
```

... gets:

```
MYGROUPCOLUMN                                                     SUM(CCC)
--------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
HI - BYE                                                                15 
next - howdy                                                            16
```

---

I do seem to have reimplemented `MIN()`, kind of. @kordirko's answer is simpler; with the same data that also gives:

```
select min(mycolumn), sum(ccc)
from (
  select case when aaa is null or length(aaa) = 0 then '(blank)' else aaa end
    || ' - ' || case when bbb is not null then bbb end as mycolumn, ccc
  from alex_collate_test
)
group by NLSSORT(mycolumn, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai')
order by NLSSORT(mycolumn, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai');

MIN(MYCOLUMN)                                                     SUM(CCC)
--------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
HI - BYE                                                                15 
next - howdy                                                            16
```

... so I'd probably go with that unless you need other analytic results anyway.